# Building the web app with json only data with javascript and ORM

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, python, extjs

I have given the new project to complete where i have separate components which talk to each other via services calls

They are not linked directly.

The technical head wants to build the entire frontend in ExtJS or jquery and then use JSON to load the data. I mean all forms , login etc will be JSON.

Now i ahve not done anything like that that. I mean i have always generated forms , data from server side controllers and views. like PHP or Django python.

I want to know that is this way good or achievable because i don't want to chnage things after spending time initially.

but is its the good way then i can start with it

Comment: jQuery would be a good place to start. It makes it really simple to send and receive JSON data, manipulate the DOM, and a bunch of other tasks. Are you looking for some sort of interface framework too?

Comment: If I understand right, you want to generate all form elements client side in javascript? What good will that do you?

Comment: I am the new developer there so its not my decision , i only have to work on what they say. They say that extjs has all grids , compoenentys , modules ready to use and it will save time. don't know if thats true or not

Comment: Then what exactly are you asking?

Comment: @korylprince I want to ask that, Is all that stuff is in theory using only json to work with UI or that can practically be done. i just want to know any drawbacks for that system or not possible or very bad idea

Comment: Yes, that can be done and can work very good. If you are using Ext JS it is the default way. If you boss would buy a license you can use Sencha Architect, which makes it easier for you to build Ext JS applications (the learning curve is pretty high in the beginning). Do you already have a backend framework to stick to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working on a *Django* project for the past six months, where I'm using *Django* for the backend service, returning only json responses, and the frontend code is completely separate.

*jQuery* by itself would result in unmaintainable code, even on a smaller scale, so you definitely need a high level frontend framework. I settled with *Durandal.js*, which includes:

- **Knockout.js** for the ui bindings
- **Sammy.js** for view routing
- **Require.js** to modularize the code

I think it was a good choice at the time, and I feel very productive with that tech stack. If I were to start from scratch again, it would be very likely a similar stack.

As for *ExtJS*, it's a component/widget based framework, which philosophy I don't very much like, I saw the future, and it wasn't written in *ExtJS* :)

Although I see *AngularJS* and *EmberJS* as the titans that will very likely win the battle of  frameworks, at least for now.

Comment: I slightly agree and slightly disagree. Ext JS will be the future for business web applications. It is not very suitable for websites, there AngularJS and EmberJS shine. The fact that more then half of the fortune 100 companies use Ext JS shows that there is a need for such a framework.